# Using own minecraft server without mojang account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

### Background:

I want to play minecraft in multiplayer mode with my 11 year old son. While I have a mojang account, he doesn't and I also don't want him to have one. At the moment we play together in singleplayer mode with my account on my Laptop using the Java Edition version 1.14.4. For multiplayer we plan to buy minecraft for his Nintendo Switch.

### My Problem:

To avoid having to have a second mojang account I decided to set up my own minecraft server. The server works, I can login on the minecraft launcher and then connect to the server an play on it. The problem is that *I still have to use my mojang account*.

What I would like to do is to manage user accounts for my server myself an use them instead of a mojang account to connect and play with my server. Can this be done?

Comment: Also, just to verify. You are aware that you *cannot* connect to a java server from the switch port of minecraft?

Comment: Warning: The original version of Minecraft is not available for the Switch. What you can buy there is a completely separate game, unfortunately having the same name. I recommend not using that one, for various reasons.

Comment: @Elva No, I wasn't aware. Thank you for pointing this out. It saved me from a bad buy.

Comment: Thank you also for the info, @FabianRöling. I'll refrain now from buying it.

Comment: Note that you can create a child account for your kid, without access to Realms etc.; still not going to go around the problem Elva mentioned, of course :)

Answer (score 4):

When you first launch the server a `server.properties` file gets created. That's where the settings for the server are stored. It's a simple text file containing `key=value` setting entries.

To disable account authentication change `online-mode` to `false`, this will do exactly what you want. Just remember not to leak the address of the server as now anyone will be able to join. Also check the file for other settings, it's very useful. :-)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. I still need to log in to my mojang account before I can select my server. And then this account is used, no other credentials can be entered. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Oh right, I forgot about the launcher bit. I guess you could use another launcher that allows you to skip Mojang authentication but I guess that's privacy territory.

Comment: Ah, so no official way then :-( Thsnks nonetheless for your help.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser I mean, you *are* using the application without a valid license; it's not too weird there's no official support for essentially stealing the game :) Every Minecraft player needs his own license and account, regardless of if you're playing online or offline. You can create a child account that doesn't have access to Realms etc. (https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/1780997-mojang-account-users-under-13).

Comment: @Luaan Playing without valid licences wasn't and isn't my goal here. I actually assumed to _have_ two licences when buying the Switch version, even though that that now turns out not to be the case. Your suggestion with a child account is not the solution I originally had in mind but it definitely is a way I can (and will) take. Thanks for that.

Comment: Weird assumption that the account somehow is the license, not the game you've purchased and would like to play... The child accounts are very limited, it's only allow multiplayer or not, so if you allow it they also can join any random "featured" server.